# Squircle template rounding

Tags: html, css

How I could make [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWylW.jpg) image working in browser? I mean, this picture has [custom borders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle)  (can't create them with CSS) which I would like to keep on my page. My plan is to make the image ([white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWylW.jpg)) transparent, which will make it possible to fill it with any CSS background. But i guess after this, the image will be like square, thanks to the transparent rounding.

Comment: `element { background: #fff url(path/to/img.png) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover; border-radius: 3rem; }`

Comment: I would like to keep border-radius from my image. Please read again.

Comment: Both of the images you show are the same... Are you saying the existing image has been cropped to have rounded borders and you're trying to figure out how to remove that so the image is square or rectangle again? You'll need to add some more detail my friend because as it reads now it's hard to know what you want.